# Can I add a class to a link

Tags: html, css

All I want to do is add a class to a link, to change the color of the linked text. Is this possible? It isn't working for me:

```
<a href="mailto:xyz.co.uk" class="black_link">xyz.co.uk</a>

.black_link a:link { color:black;}
.black_link a:visited { color:black;}
.black_link a:hover { color:pink;}
.black_link a:active { color:pink; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please try to come up with better class names. "link" is redundant, it's an `<a>` element. "black" describes the appearance, you should describe the purpose (i.e. the reason you want the appearance to be different).

Comment: Yes you *can*, but note that `.black_link a` will select all `<a>` elements which are descendants of elements having `.black_link` class. In this case you should use that like `a.black_link` instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've got my head round it now! Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are targeting `<a> tag` globally then use

```
a:link { color:blue;} 
a:visited { color:black;} 
a:hover { color:pink;} 
a:active { color:pink;}
```

if you are using class in `<a> tag` you can do it in two ways.

```
1st
   a.black_link:link { color:blue;} 
   a.black_link:visited { color:black;} 

2nd
  .black_link:link{color:blue;}
  .black_link:visited{color:pink;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is incorrect. Use selectors as mentioned below:

```css
a.black_link:link { color:black;}
a.black_link:visited { color:black;}
a.black_link:hover { color:pink;}
a.black_link:active { color:pink; }
```

```html
<a href="mailto:xyz.co.uk" class="black_link">xyz.co.uk</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

```
a.black_link:link { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect, from your css `.black_link a` will select all `<a>` elements which are descendants of elements having `.black_link` class. In this case you should use that like `a.black_link` instead. You can change your css as:

```
a.black_link:link { color:black;}
a.black_link:visited { color:black;}
a.black_link:hover { color:pink;}
a.black_link:active { color:pink; }

<a href="mailto:xyz.co.uk" class="black_link">xyz.co.uk</a>
```

P.S search for similar questions before asking common questions.